# Zoom (seminar software) keeps hanging (Elementary Hera)

Tags: release-hera, applications, kernel

Since the last kernel update (5.3.0-51) zoom takes almost 5 minutes to open. Until that time the whole operating system hangs and I can't do anything else. All I can do is wait for it to kick off.... This is quite crippling especially when I have appointments back to back.

I've erased the entire drive and done a clean install of the OS hoping to resolve the problem but it persists....any idea, any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. I thought it might be the recent updates to the Zoom client, but you think it's more related to the kernel?

Does it also only affect your display, as in, audio seems to work ok? What graphics card do you use - I'm using the built-in Intel HD graphics chip.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed related to the kernel updates, and affects the Intel HD graphics card driver. There's a fix in the next kernel release (5.30-52): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1872001

The alternative is to roll back to 5.30-45 (https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/g9vxce/zoom_freezing_in_linux_kernel_greater_than_53045/)

To verify if you're affected by this, run `journalctl -b | grep i915`, and look for lines that say `Resetting rcs0 for hang on rcs0` around the same time that you're attempting to use Zoom.